# Copy String from an android from EditText into String variable on Android

Tags: android

I have a class that creates a view to gather data via a function `getView()` that provides a view with an EditText.

This class has also has variable `answer`.
When the user chances the EditText I want to store the content of the EditText in `answer`.

If I would use an onKeyListener I fear that the answer will probably get stored before the last letter is entered.

Is there a good way to handle this in the `getView()` function via some other listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) to your `EditText` and implement in your class [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Then you will just take the text from the methods and store in your `answer`

Comment: Thanks, I missed it because I thought such a function would have to be named setTextChangedListener :(

Comment: Probably there is a good reason they call it `add` and not `set`. Probably they let us to add more listeneres than one (in case of using set)